# Using filter() to remove items from a list that DO NOT contain part of a string - jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, filtering

I have a `$list` of html links I'm trying to filter. Each link has a `data-foo` attribute. If `true`, I need to remove any link where `data-foo` equals a string with "bar" somewhere in it. Else, remove every link *without* "bar" in it.

```
if (true) {
    $list.filter('[data-foo*="bar"]').remove();
} else {
    $list.filter('[data-foo*="!bar"]').remove();
}
```

The first part where I'm removing each link with "bar" somewhere in the `data-foo` attribute works perfectly. However, I have no idea how to remove each link that *does not* have "bar" somewhere in the attribute.

I've tried putting a `!` in various places but it's just causing errors. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `filter(function)`

```
$list.filter('[data-foo]').filter(function() {
  var hasBar = $(this).data('foo').indexOf('bar') > -1;
  return bar_only_condition_boolean ? hasBar : !hasBar;
}).remove();
```